# Changing table data

Tags: jtable, jbutton

I have table shown in the app and I'd like to get search button which will change the data shown in the table.

How to do that ?

```
    txSearch = new JTextField();
    txSearch.setBounds(107, 11, 150, 20);
    contentPane.add(txSearch);
    txSearch.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnSearch = new JButton("Search");
    btnSearch.setBounds(261, 10, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnSearch);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your TableModel? you would implement ActionListener for this button and write a method to access the data held by TableModel.

Comment: I have my tablemodel in separate class, currently I think I'll need the table model to implement tablemodellistener to fire the change while the jbutton set the action, still figuring out if I get the right idea on how to do this

Comment: I can't use self-reply yet before some more hours, so I guess I'll have to post part of the codes by the next day as it's long enough to be placed in comment

Answer (score 0):

Here's part of the code :

```
class QueryTableModel extends AbstractTableModel implements TableModelListener{


      while (rs.next()) {
        String[] record = new String[colCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
          record[i] = rs.getString(i + 1);
        }
        cache.addElement(record);
      }
      fireTableChanged(null); // notify everyone that we have a new table.
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
      cache = new Vector<String[]>(); // blank it out and keep going.
      e.printStackTrace();
      }
}

@Override
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: I added in "implement TableModelListener" in my code and along with that the override statement was created as result, where I think I should place the what the table has to do...a listener, while somewhere in the main...UI with buttons and stuffs I have to define an action trigger. That's what I currently think though the how-to is still a bit blurry...